# Response code when etag is expected but not received?

Tags: http

What would be an appropriate HTTP response code for a server to send if it expects the ETag header to be set but the request does not contain it ?
Would the most appropriate be BAD REQUEST (400) ?

Comment: NB "ETag" isn't a valid header for an HTTP Request. You probably mean to use "If-None-Match".

Comment: I actually mean to send the ETag header with the request since it is a PATCH request and the ETag identifies the patch document.

Comment: Again, "ETag" is not a request header field. ETags are assigned by the server.

Comment: I understand this now. The current standard does not make this distinction very clear. I have assumed that ETag is a header that can be used to describe the payload/message by both client and server. ( There are also others that use ETag in this manner. see http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide/content/Create_Update_Object-d1e1965.html ) The new draft is much more explicit and clearer regarding this. Thank you for your input !

Answer (score 2):

The [description in RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) defines Status **403** as "The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it."

Since it is explicitly left up to the server to explain *why* the request was refused, a 403 with a body stating "All requests must include an ETag Header" would seem to be a correct response.

Status 400 is defined in that RFC as being due to "malformed syntax", which is not the same as receiving a request you didn't like the look of.

Comment: a) there is no ETag request header field, so you can't require it; b) the description of status code 400 in RFC 2616 is misleading, see http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-22.html#status.400 instead.

Comment: @JulianReschke The current RFC seems pretty explicit to me, unless you can link to another *current* specification that conflicts. The *draft* you link to seems to propose *changing* those status codes, so 400 is broader and 403 narrower. To me, its definitions of 401 and 403 appear to overlap (credentials can be "refused" with 401 or "insufficient" with 403), but regardless of that it isn't yet a standard.

Comment: IMSoP: the draft broadens the definition of 400 because it has to be a superset of all 4xx codes (by definition). That being said: the draft is in Last Call, so if you disagree with what it says I recommend that you provide feedback to the IETF HTTPbis Working Group. Otherwise, this is what the "standard" (*) will say very soon. (* for some value of "standard")

Comment: @JulianReschke Fair enough on the "nearly standard", but the appendix does list this as a change, not a clarification: "The 400 (Bad Request) status code has been relaxed so that it isn't limited to syntax errors (Section 6.5.1)." I'm not sure there is any requirement that x00 statuses be more general (can Status 300 be considered a superset of all 3xx codes, for instance), only that certain semantics are attached to the first digit (all 4xx are similar)

Comment: @JulianReschke : The draft does indeed not mention the ETag as a request header field. However, it seems that the draft also does not list more common request header fields such as "Content-Type". Is there any reason why they are not part of the request header section  in the draft?

Comment: Am I interpreting the draft correctly that for the error case, that i would like to describe, a 400 response code would be more appropriate than 403 response code ?

Comment: JE42: your error cases doesn't make sense, so there is no status code to recommend. Also, the draft I cited is one of six specs that will replace RFC 2616, so you need to look for Content-Type elsewhere (in Part 2).

Comment: Reading Julian's answer I think that 428 would be a better response than 403.

Comment: @JulianReschke Thanks for the pointer ! This actually means that I am using ETag in away that is not part of HTTP protocol. I will rename the header and prefix it with "X-" to mark it as a custom header, that should fix the semantic issues.

Comment: JE42 - Don't. There's nothing special about "X-". Better explain what problem you want to solve.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that X- has been deprecated. Didnt know that. ( found tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6648 ) The problem i would like to solve is: i am sending a PATCH document to the server and would like to use an id to check if the server has received this document before, so that the server does not reapply / reprocess it. The patch doc has a different form than the actual resource.

Comment: @JulianReschke that would be an option however it would require the server to unzip+parse the payload first before the server can checkout if its a duplicate, thus putting this info in the header seems to have more advantages from the application's point of view.

Answer (score 2):

If what you mean is that a *conditional* request header field (such as If-None-Match) was missing, then the answer would be status 428 (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585#section-3).

Comment: I really meant to send the ETag in the request to describe the entity that is being send as part of the request.

Comment: Please please please don't bastardize HTTP or try to invent your own protocol! The "If-Match" family of HTTP headers are designed for what you're trying to do so use them.

Comment: If-Match has a different semantic. If-Match matches aginst the etag of the resource itself - however, the document i am sending to the resource endpoint has a different document type ( since its a patch doc), so etag matching would not make sense in this case.

Comment: JE42 - the main issue is that you haven't explained yet *what* you are trying to do with the Etag; if you did, we might be able to recommend something else

Answer (score 0):

Is it a conditional GET? Because then a plain 200 OK with full body seems completely appropriate to me in case the validity of the client cache can not be verified.